# How to use useeffect on every render our specific render

Tags: reactjs, redux

Good evening!

I am building weather app. So basically i have MAIN PAGE where i have my Search component for type city to get info about it. But when i am first render that page i don't see any info ofc it's obvious. So i want to getUserLocation and in the first component where i run my app i want to create useEffect with function inside it, then i get lat and lon from my import function then i make a request to API to get info about city based on user location. When i am get all info i will dispatch that data to my reducer and from reducer i will update my main.page. So it's works.I run my app, i see login page, under the hood i am getting user location then dispatch and upadate reducer then set info on main.page. When i am log in i can see that data but when i refresh page, data's gonne. So how to again run my useeffect
Code below:

```html
useEffect(() => {
        const updateDateBasedOnUserLocation = async () => {
            try{
                const {lat, lon} = await getCoords();
                console.log(lat, lon)
                const response = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${KEY}&units=metric`)
                console.log(response)
                const data = await response.json();
                console.log(data)
                dispatch(REQUEST_SUCCESS({
                    city: data.name,
                    temp: Math.round(data.main.temp),
                    feels_like: data.main.feels_like,
                    wind: data.wind.speed,
                    humidity: data.main.humidity,
                    pressure: data.main.pressure
                },))
            }
            catch(err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        }
        updateDateBasedOnUserLocation()
    }, )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an array of dependencies to useEffect.

If you want to run it only on the first render it should be empty.

```
useEffect(() => {
   // Do something
}, []);
```

If you want to run when a dependency change.

```
useEffect(() => {
   // Do something
}, [dependency]);
```